# Grunt imagemin for multiple locations

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-imagemin

I am trying to add Grunts imagemin plugin and it is working fine if I want to work in one directory only. However I have a multilingual site and therefore I have separate image directories for both English and French images. Is there a way to apply this plugin so it watches both directories and sends the compressed images to different destinations?

Here is what I have at the moment as the standard implementation:

```
imagemin: {
    dymanic: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'English/assets/img/',
            src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
            dest: 'English/assets/img/build/'
        }]
    }
}
```

What I need to do is also add a French location in the 'cwd' field and a French destination in the 'dest' field but I don't know how to add this to the existing code.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the simple answer in case anyone else is having this issue. I simply change `dynamic` to a unique name and then copied the code again and gave it a new name. Example below:

```
imagemin: {
    English: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'English/assets/img/',
            src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
            dest: 'English/assets/img/build/'
        }]
    },
    French: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'French/assets/img/',
            src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
            dest: 'French/assets/img/build/'
        }]
    }
}
```

If anyone knows of a shorter way to achieve this then please let me know. Otherwise this appears to work exactly as I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need use: dynamic {} or static {}, you can remove English and french will works perfect.

see: [Grunt imagemin running but not minifying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996413/grunt-imagemin-running-but-not-minifying/33041219#33041219)